# Showing a different form in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've looked at a few different threads and tried to find the proper answer, none have worked. I am trying to hide the **current** Form. I know how to do that, but when I do *ProjectName.Form2.Visible()* it gives me an error and says to just use *Visible()*, unfortunately, that makes Form1 visible.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. It would be a good idea to add some code that can help everyone here understand the issue and try to help you. You can use this guideline for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually form does not have a `Visible()` method, and has a boolean `Visible` Property and `Show()` Method:

And please note that you should first create an instance of Form2, and then call it's `Show()` method, or set it's `Visible` property to true.

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Visible = true;  // or frm.Show();
```

Comment: Everything is working except for the CurPass string. 
`    if (textBox1.Text == curPass || textBox1.Text == "Cameron33" || textBox1.Text == "completebetakey")
            {
                Form2 frm = new Form2();
                frm.Show();
                Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Yikes. That's incorrect.", "Uh oh.");
            }`
I'm getting the "Yikes. That's incorrect." message when I put in the curPass string, but in a normal pass ("Cameron33") it works perfectly

Comment: This approach is not nice, could you come to chat, please? [https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180124/ashkan-mobayen-khiabani](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180124/ashkan-mobayen-khiabani)

Comment: does the file the curPass is read from exist in the executable path? may be you don't have the file or its in wrong path.

Comment: I don't have 20 rep, do you have a discord?

Comment: oh you need reps to join chats? my skype id is `am.pro` . do you have skype?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new instance of the form and call `.Visible()` on that instance.

```
var newForm = new ProjectName.Form2();
newForm.Visible();
```

When you call `ProjectName.Form2.Visible()` it looks for a static method on the class called `Visible` which does not exist.

Comment: Member 'Form2.Visible()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @Exvient read my second paragraph. When you call it like that you are trying to access a static method that does not exist. You need to create an instance of the form like in the code sample that I provided

Comment: I did :P
var newForm = new JadeComplete.Form2();
                newForm.Visible();
                Hide();

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to Show the form after instantiation:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
Visible = false;
```

I'm frankly not sure whether forms can be just shown without running that method or not, it's just how I've always done it. Also as Ashkan mentions above, Show is a method while Visible is a bool property.